# Error al intentar conectar una cámara JAI AD_132GE#1 con Python, utilizando la librería Harvester

Tags: python, ip, conexión

Estoy comenzando a utilizar cámaras IP, y tengo que realizar la captura de una imagen, en específico de la cámara JAI AD-132GE por medio de Python, estoy comenzando por utilizar la librería Harvester que por lo visto me permitiría realizar dicha conexión, sin embargo no he logrado obtener imágenes.

He utilizado el la herramienta que JAI proporciona JAI Camera Control Tool y con ella si logro realizar la adquisición de imágen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

sin embargo al querer enlazarlo en Python obtengo un error, este es el código:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from harvesters.core import Harvester

# create harvester object
h = Harvester()
h.add_cti_file("c:/Program Files/JAI/SDK/bin/JaiGevTL.cti")
h.update_device_info_list()
h.device_info_list[0]

# create image acquirer
ia = h.create_image_acquirer(0)
width = 2560
height = 1960
ia.device.node_map.Width.value, ia.device.node_map.Height.value = width, height
ia.device.node_map.PixelFormat.value = 'Mono8'

# create videowriter
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
fps = 25.0
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, fps, (width,height))

# start image aq
ia.start_image_acquisition()
while(True):
    with ia.fetch_buffer() as buffer:
        # Let's create an alias of the 2D image component:
        component = buffer.payload.components[0]

        #     # Let's see the acquired data in 1D:
        #    _1d = component.data

        # Reshape the NumPy array into a 2D array:
        frame = component.data.reshape(component.height, component.width)
    
        # perform any operation on the image
    
        # convert to bgr for video saving
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR) 

        # save frames
        out.write(frame)
    
        # save snapshot
        #    cv2.imwrite('snap.jpg', frame)
    
        # show live acquisition
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    
        # exit live aq with "q"-key
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
ia.stop_image_acquisition()
ia.destroy()
h.reset()
```

Este es el error que me arroja al correr el programa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería si alguien tiene idea de cual puede ser el fallo y pudiera instruirme en el tema, saludos.